# wp_customize_support_script - do I need it?

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer

I've noticed a random JavaScript function at the end of the source code of my WordPress website.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var request, b = document.body, c = 'className', cs = 'customize-support', rcs = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)(no-)?'+cs+'(\\s+|$)');

                request = true;

        b[c] = b[c].replace( rcs, ' ' );
        // The customizer requires postMessage and CORS (if the site is cross domain)
        b[c] += ( window.postMessage && request ? ' ' : ' no-' ) + cs;
    }());
</script>
```

A quick google search lead me to the article below, but I didn't find it very informative.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_customize_support_script/

Does anyone know what *exactly* this script does, and if it is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is needed. For reference, the function's description is:

> Prints a script to check whether or not the Customizer is supported, and apply either the no-customize-support or customize-support class to the body.

The class names that the function toggles on the `body` element control whether or not the Customize link in the admin bar is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally found the fix.

In my case  tag was missing the ">" at the end.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

instead of:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>
```

Maybe this will help anyone else.

Comment: So the script in the question was appearing on your page? (It's not immediately obvious to me that this is a fix for the same issue)

Comment: @Rup yes, exactly. That script is being shown before header (see screenshot:  [link](https://i.imgur.com/OTU5Pq7.png). Just added the ">" to close the body tag and the problem was fixed. I've found it looking in the page source [link](https://i.imgur.com/f48XDiM.png); you can also do that.

Comment: this was also my problem ;)